# sql statement binding result with detail

Tags: sql, oracle, data-binding, master-detail

i have query below :

```
select s.ST_SAMPLE_ID, s.st_cn_no as CNNumber,
s.st_smptyp as SampleType,
s.st_wasgrp as WasteCode,
s.st_wascod as WasteCategory,
s.st_received_dt as ReceivedDate,
s.st_wastyp_name as WasteType,
s.st_status as SampleStatus,
s.st_dispose_ind as DisposalStatus,
s.st_container as SampleContainer,
s.st_smppnt as SamplePoint,
s.st_nature as SampleNature,
c.scm_name as Color,cm_client_name 
from sample_txn s,sample_color_mstr c,client_mstr cm  
where s.st_color=scm_auto_no (+) and st_client_id=cm_client_id 
and st_year='13' and s.st_lab_id='R'and to_char(s.st_received_dt, 'MON') = 'FEB'
```

and there is second query

```
select TC.CM_COMPO_NAME as "COMPONENT",CM_SYMBOL as SYM,
CT_UNIT_Name as UOM,CT_METHOD_NAME as "METHOD",
ct_det_status as "REP. LIMITS",
  ct_ts_status as "TEST SPEC.", c.ct_due_dt as "DUE DATE",
  ct_result as "RESULT",ct_rep as "REP",ct_version as "VER",
FROM COMPONENT_TXN C,CODES_MSTR CM, SAMPLE_TXN S, 
  COMPONENT_MSTR TC,  INSTRUMENT_MSTR I
```

with each result :

[result of query 1 and 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5j33el6l3heav3c/aaaa.jpg) *sorry cannot insert image and just link, due to less of reputation*

i want to bind query 1 and 2 into one query, so can select all value like this system show below :

[system show](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvmstmmt3vn395w/7-2-2014%203-27-52%20PM.jpg) *sorry cannot insert image and just link, due to less of reputation*

i have try to combine those query like this

```
select s.ST_SAMPLE_ID, s.st_cn_no as CNNumber,
s.st_smptyp as SampleType,
s.st_wasgrp as WasteCode,
s.st_wascod as WasteCategory,
s.st_received_dt as ReceivedDate,
s.st_wastyp_name as WasteType,
s.st_status as SampleStatus,
s.st_dispose_ind as DisposalStatus,
s.st_container as SampleContainer,
s.st_smppnt as SamplePoint,
s.st_nature as SampleNature,
c.scm_name as Color,cm_client_name 
TC.CM_COMPO_NAME as "COMPONENT",CM_SYMBOL as SYM,
CT_UNIT_Name as UOM,CT_METHOD_NAME as "METHOD",
ct_det_status as "REP. LIMITS",
  ct_ts_status as "TEST SPEC.", o.ct_due_dt as "DUE DATE",
  ct_result as "RESULT",ct_rep as "REP",ct_version as "VER"
from sample_txn s,sample_color_mstr c,client_mstr cm, component_txn o,codes_master cm,
component_mstr tc, instrument_mstr i
where s.st_color=scm_auto_no (+) and st_client_id=cm_client_id 
and st_year='13' and s.st_lab_id='R'and to_char(s.st_received_dt, 'MON') = 'FEB'
```

but then error appear

```
Error at Command Line:13 Column:2
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thank you

Comment: comma, after cm_client name!

Answer (score 0):

The `intrument_mstr` and `component_txn` tables are never joined, and this is going to give you catersian join.

```
select s.ST_SAMPLE_ID, s.st_cn_no as CNNumber,
s.st_smptyp as SampleType,
s.st_wasgrp as WasteCode,
s.st_wascod as WasteCategory,
s.st_received_dt as ReceivedDate,
s.st_wastyp_name as WasteType,
s.st_status as SampleStatus,
s.st_dispose_ind as DisposalStatus,
s.st_container as SampleContainer,
s.st_smppnt as SamplePoint,
s.st_nature as SampleNature,
c.scm_name as Color,
cm_client_name,
TC.CM_COMPO_NAME as "COMPONENT",
CM_SYMBOL as SYM,
CT_UNIT_Name as UOM,
CT_METHOD_NAME as "METHOD",
ct_det_status as "REP. LIMITS",
ct_ts_status as "TEST SPEC.",
o.ct_due_dt as "DUE DATE",
ct_result as "RESULT",
ct_rep as "REP",
ct_version as "VER"
from sample_txn s,
     sample_color_mstr c,
     client_mstr cm,
     component_txn o,
     codes_master cm,
     component_mstr tc,
     instrument_mstr i
where s.st_color=scm_auto_no (+)
 and st_client_id=cm_client_id 
 and st_year='13' 
 and s.st_lab_id='R'
 and to_char(s.st_received_dt, 'MON') = 'FEB'
```